# Need to count field based on value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

We have mongo 3.2. we have collection name test5.
It has many field and array ( undaries.couies.ZIPCodes.status )

Status field has few values like Add1 & Add2

I want to take COUNT based on status=ADD1 or ADD2

```
"**undaries**" : [
    {
        "**couies**" : [
            {
                "**ZIPCodes**" : [
                    {
                        "ZIPCode" : "60349", 
                        "city" : "Test", 
                        "household" : "Test2", 
                        "accounts" : "0", 
                        "SD" : "Y", 
                        "**status**" : "Add1", 
                        "lastUpdateDate" : "2017-01-24T09:39:56.417Z", 
                        "lastUpdateBy" : "Test"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "ZIPCode" : "60234", 
                        "city" : "Test", 
                        "household" : "test1", 
                        "accounts" : "0", 
                        "SD" : "Y", 
                        "status" : "Add2", 
                        "lastUpdateDate" : "2017-01-24T09:39:56.417Z", 
                        "lastUpdateBy" : "Test"
                    },
                    {
                        "ZIPCode" : "60235", 
                        "city" : "Test", 
                        "household" : "test1", 
                        "accounts" : "0", 
                        "SD" : "Y", 
                        "status" : "Add1", 
                        "lastUpdateDate" : "2017-01-24T09:39:56.417Z", 
                        "lastUpdateBy" : "Test"
                    }................
```

How to get total count of status based on value.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: `something.find( { $or: [ { status: { "ADD1" ,"add2"} ] } )`

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `count()` method and the `$in` operator

```
db.yourCollection.count({"undaries.couies.ZIPCodes.status":{$in : ["Add1", "Add2"]}})
```

`count()` is shorthand for `.find({query}).count()`